# custom string delimiters stringtemplate-4

Tags: java, android, stringtemplate, stringtemplate-4

I am trying to use stringtemplate-4 engine in android.

But I need starting delimiter,

```
 " {{ "
```

while ending delimiter should be,

```
" }} "
```

Here, I think only char delimiters are allowed. 
So how to use string delimiters?

Thnx in advance.

Comment: StringTemplate has a single `char` pair for delimiters. You could replace `{{`/`}}` with a special unused Unicode char, like `◄` and `►`.

Comment: @JoopEggen, perhaps make that an answer?

Comment: @BartKiers I still hope someone has a code based solution.

Comment: @JoopEggen thnx but I need exact what I mentioned.

Comment: @JoopEggen, ah, I see. I thought you were sure there was no way to allow string delimiters.

Comment: @user2732017, then it seems you're out of luck. I'm also not 100% sure, put I think it is not possible.

Comment: can anybody suggest an alternative, so I can use custom delimters?

Answer (score 4):

StringTemplate only supports using single characters as the delimiter. This limitation is coded in several places, including but not limited to the following.

1. The [`STGroup`](http://www.stringtemplate.org/api/org/stringtemplate/v4/STGroup.html) constructors, and the `delimiterStartChar` and `delimiterStopChar` fields of the same class are represented as the type `char`, not `String`.
2. The [`STLexer`](http://www.stringtemplate.org/api/org/stringtemplate/v4/compiler/STLexer.html) constructors face a similar restriction. In addition, the lexer implementation only uses a single-character lookahead operation to identify delimiters.

You would need to fork the project and rewrite several portions of the code to support arbitrary strings as delimiters.