# Creating custom delimiter in stringtemplate

Tags: java, stringtemplate, stringtemplate-4

String Template uses `<...>` or `$...$` as delimiters. I need to have a custom delimiter, something like `<<...>>`. Is this possible?

The code below accepts only character for the start and end delimiters:

```
ST st = new ST("<< token >>", '<<', '>>');
```

Answer (score 0):

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24265600/3380056) states, unfortunately you can only use single character delimiters in String Template :(